# Ask for login before submitting a form or before you see content of page

Tags: javascript, authentication, netlify, netlify-form

I have a form in my website for sending a maintenance request.

So before submitting the form, I want a pop-up asking the user to log in or immediately after you land on the page the login should pop up before continuing.

My question is :

How can I trigger the login option to display on the page or allow the user to fill out the form but most be logged in before the submit button works? I am using Netlify identity for authentication

Thank you.